# Log file on the datagridview

Tags: vb.net

So, I am making a little bit complex code on my delete method on the `datagridview` in other words, after I select a row and click delete it will be removed from the database. To control this I would like to make a log file where I can see what was deleted with it.

If I've used a normal delete with a `button` and a `textbox` it could be easier then the actual code that I have. So I've made some search and found this piece of code that seams nice to me. I will show you it and then explain you guys what I really want.

```
TextBox1.Text = ""
Dim FirstValue As Boolean = True
Dim cell As DataGridViewCell
For Each cell In DataGridView1.SelectedCells
If Not FirstValue Then
   TextBox1.Text += ", "
End If
TextBox1.Text += cell.Value.ToString()
FirstValue = False
Next
```

What I would like to do is after delete some row from `datagridview` it will recognize my first column, because it is what I really want on the log file. So it will write on the `textbox` and then it will read on Log file. Do you have any ideia I could I solve my problem with this code that I got.

Comment: Why do you need to write this code in the user interface? Logging that a database row was deleted is something that should happen at the database layer of your code. At that point, you should not be dealing with datagridviews and textboxes at all, but with strings and numbers.

Comment: You are talking about Logfile right? No, I don't want it to show into the user interface that's why I will use that Textbox invisibly

Comment: I didn't mean showing it into the UI, I meant *coding* it in the UI part of your code. The code that handles database writing and logging should be in a separate file (or even a separate project) and it should have no idea what your interface looks like at all. Google "separate business logic from user interface" and read around a bit. Also, don't use invisible textboxes to hold data, that is what variables are for.

Comment: So I have to study it more then I thought ahahah